# Inferring Sequence of Distinct Objects From Historical Data

Tags: predictive-models, ranking, combinatorics

I have K distinct objects that are stocked at a shop every day. I'd like to use data from prior days to predict the order in which items will be sold today. Is there a straightforward way to predict today's order from orders observed in previous days? I've tried searching literature on this, and I haven't come up with much.

In problem, I only know the order in which each item was sold on each day, and it's possible (but not guaranteed) that more recent days are likely to be better predictors of what will happen today. It's also important to note that some items might not be sold every day, and some items might never be sold over a long time window. The data model is a table with the following columns:

- Date (ordinal)
- Unique Item Identifier (categorical)
- Order Sold (positive integer from 1 to K, with items never sold placed with a marker value of K)

If I had an effective predictor of this order, there are a few things that I could imagine doing to optimize my business, like keeping things unlikely to sell early far in the back of my shop until the end of the day. If there are trade-offs to make, I'm probably happier getting things more correct earlier in the sequence at the expense of the later parts of the sequence.

Comment: This is an interesting question and has several possible good solutions.  It would be nice, then, to have more information to guide the choice of solution.  For instance, what advantages or benefits would you gain from such a prediction?  What would it cost you for the prediction to be a little wrong?  How much would a "little" be?